# setTimeout() function triggering an error

Tags: jquery, recursion, settimeout

Wanted to run the function `a` every 5 seconds but only 3 seconds after the main function is executed on fully loaded document.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'engine_start.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    //audioElement.load()

    $.get();

    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
    }, true);

   $('.car').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
    });


}, 3000);


function a {
setTimeout(function() { 
$('.light').attr("src","images/light-on.png");  
}, 2500);   
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting???

Comment: its running fine but not running in loop./... how to run function A again n again

Comment: Why change the image source all the time to the same image?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `Function a` after every 5 second, then use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimout()`:

```
setInterval(function(){ a(); }, 5000);

function a {
  $('.light').attr("src","images/light-on.png");
}
```

Comment: it will run again n again or 1 time?

Comment: It will run again n again @Shafqat

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` which will run again and again after 5 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
     $('.light').attr("src","images/light-on.png");
}, 5000);
```